# drag-and-drop folder content ( and subdirectories ) in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, usability

how can a drag and drop a folder with music and other directories of music to a web-app ( in this case rails but i think the solution must be general ) to get the paths of all the songs so that i can have an online music player for local content . Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With focus on the usability tag: I think its most common to "select files" from the web app rather than "drag and drop" into the web app.

When it comes to implementing the drag and drop feature, I think that JavaScript is a more important keyword than ruby.  This feature must be implemented client side after all.

You should take a look at this question:
[HTML5 drag-drop uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263118/html5-drag-drop-uploads)